# Using Hashtable to store properties to combat serialization versioning

Tags: c#, serialization

Other then the speed issues when accessing and hashtable and casting value types, is this really very bad?

```
[Serializable]
public class Cheat : ISerializable
{
    public Cheat() { }

    public string Orange { get { return Convert.ToString(_mData["Orange"]); } set { _mData["Orange"] = value; } }

    public List<int> Ints { get { return (List<int>)(_mData["Ints"]); } set { _mData["Ints"] = value; } }

    #region ISerializable Members

    protected Hashtable _mData = new Hashtable();

    protected Cheat(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        _mData = (Hashtable)info.GetValue("_mData", typeof(Hashtable));
    }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("_mData", _mData);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: In terms of what? In .NET 2.0+ newer versions of data model properties that are not recognised will be automatically ignored when deserialisation occurs. No code is required for this behaviour when using BinaryFormatter.

Comment: I don't know in terms of what else it can be bad. That is why I am asking. I already read about the NET 2.0 improvements and OptionValue options from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(v=vs.80).aspx but using Hashtable seems to solve the immediate problem easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `ISerializable` interface for serialisation you are essentially taking control over the serialisation process. This allows you full control over handing versioning of serialised model classes. So you could even deserialise to a completely different class if you wanted to. Given the example above, serialisation into a Hashtable does not add value.

As you have pointed out it decreases speed because you have to unbox the objects for each property request. If you have lots of property reads then this could really add up.

A hashtable scenario like this would be best used when you had to pass immutable types like string up several layers to a calling method. In that case leaving the properties boxed may be of some benefit. However because your `_mData` field is protected and you are specifically exposing properties with types of `List<int>` and `string` then I assume you do not intend to do this.
If you wanted to continue your model you should at the very least cache your properties as strongly typed fields and covert type only once on first read.

Specially relating to versioning, if you expect the model to be updated in the future or have a definite need for compatibility allow for that now so that model versions can be identified. Previously when I have done this I have used a marker field (or XML attribute for XML serialisation) with a version number.

My suggestion would be to just serialise and deserialise to the types you need. If you version your class latter then allow for compatibility in you protected constructor and `GetObjectData` method.

Comment: "you should at the very least cache your properties as strongly typed fields and covert type only once on first read." -- I thought of that after posting the question. The issue with using a version marker field is that I have to put conditional clauses in constructor to determine what to deseralise and what not to. If a new programmer comes in he has to know every single version of the class that is in use before he can avoid errors. I'll give it a bit more thought. Thanks.